# How to access database running on WSL2 from Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, ubuntu-22.04, yugabytedb, virtual-ethernet

I use YugabyteDB running on WSL2.
My `./yugabyted status` shows:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                yugabyted                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Status              : Running.                                                                           |
| Replication Factor  : 1                                                                                  |
| YugabyteDB UI       : http://127.0.1.1:15433                                                             |
| JDBC                : jdbc:postgresql://127.0.1.1:5433/yugabyte?user=yugabyte&password=yugabyte          |
| YSQL                : bin/ysqlsh -h 127.0.1.1  -U yugabyte -d yugabyte                                   |
| YCQL                : bin/ycqlsh 127.0.1.1 9042 -u cassandra                                             |
```

WSL2 uses virtual ethernet so I couldn't access `YugabyteDB UI` by `http://127.0.1.1:15433`.

So I used `wsl ip addr show` and used `eth0` address (`172.25.78.212/20`) to connect to YugabyteDB UI. It works (http://172.25.78.212:15433). So I wanted to connect to database, that's my connection string:

```
Host=172.25.78.212; Port=5433; Database=yugabyte; Username=yugabyte; Password=yugabyte
```

But I cannot. I get `SocketException` that says:

> A connection cannot be established because the target computer actively refuses to connect

So how can I access the database running on WSL2 from Windows? I use Ubuntu22.04 (as WSL2).

Comment: Can you try connecting to YCQL? Can you get some logs and upload them `./yugabyted collect_logs` ?